# Strange csvsimple output when the line starts with an accented character

Tags: errors, csv, csvsimple

The code example below produces an undesirable result, where an Omega appears  on the 5th line and all data from the 6th line appears glued to the last cell in the 5th line.

Does anyone knows what might be causing this misbehavior?

[image: n]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{corpusabg.csv}
word,frequency,phonetic transcription,phone length,syllabic transcription,syllable length,average duration
de,125749,de,2,CV,1,-1
que,116882,ke,2,CV,1,-1
a,102779,a,1,V,1,-1
o,91246,o,1,V,1,-1
e,87868,e,1,V,1,-1
é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1
eu,46558,eW,2,VG,1,-1
do,46538,do,2,CV,1,-1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\parbox[t]{4em}{\centering\bfseries#1\par\kern1mm}}

\csvreader[no head,column count=6,tabular=rrrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{corpusabg.csv}{}{%
  \csviffirstrow{\myhead{\csvcoli} & \myhead{\csvcolii} & \myhead{\csvcoliii}
    & \myhead{\csvcoliv} & \myhead{\csvcolv} & \myhead{\csvcolvi}
    }{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly _why_ the package does this, but the answer to that can tagged `expansion`, `UTF8-sequence`, and `fragile`. If you wrap the `é` in braces (_i.e._ `{é}`) it works, though :) It seems that the package grabs the first byte of `é` as argument and breaks the UTF8 sequence, ensuing chaos. For instance, if you use `aé` it works. So wrapping in braces seems to be the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Using braces did work. :-)  Strange... it seems the problem only happens when the accent happens in the first char.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this bit of code in `csvsimple.sty`:

```
\if\csv@par\csvline\relax%
  \else%
  \csv@escanline{\csvline}%
  % check and decide
  \csv@opt@checkcolumncount%
\fi%
```

here `\csvline` is the line which was just read and `\csv@par` is `\par`. When the read line is `é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1`, the test is:

```
\if\csv@par é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1\relax%
  \else%
  \csv@escanline{\csvline}%
  % check and decide
  \csv@opt@checkcolumncount%
\fi%
```

This will (with pdfTeX, of course) expand `é`, which is `\u8:é`, which then further expands into some gibberish. After a complete expansion of this, the resulting test is basically:

```
\if\csv@par\unhbox <strange bytes>é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1\relax%
  \else%
  \csv@escanline{\csvline}%
  % check and decide
  \csv@opt@checkcolumncount%
\fi%
```

which returns true because `\csv@par` and `\unhbox` are the same for `\if`. Then the code executed is `<strange bytes>é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1\relax` and you saw what that makes.

The easiest solution is to wrap the `é` in braces:

```
{é},61550,3,1,V,1,-1
```

so that the test compares `\csv@par` with `{` which will be false and the code will do the right thing.

If for some reason you can't/don't want to change the CSV file, then you can try this patch:

```
\def\csv@def@par{\par}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\csvloop
  {\if\csv@par}
  {\ifx\csv@def@par}
  {}{\ERROR! Failed to patch}
```

It will replace the problematic test with one that will test for `\par` without expanding things. BEWARE! I don't know if the purpose of that test it to check for `\par` or something, so this might break more things than fix. Use at your own risk!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\csv@def@par{\par}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\csvloop
  {\if\csv@par}
  {\ifx\csv@def@par}
  {}{\ERROR! Failed to patch}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{corpusabg.csv}
word,frequency,phonetic transcription,phone length,syllabic transcription,syllable length,average duration
de,125749,de,2,CV,1,-1
que,116882,ke,2,CV,1,-1
a,102779,a,1,V,1,-1
o,91246,o,1,V,1,-1
e,87868,e,1,V,1,-1
é,61550,3,1,V,1,-1
eu,46558,eW,2,VG,1,-1
do,46538,do,2,CV,1,-1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\parbox[t]{4em}{\centering\bfseries#1\par\kern1mm}}

\csvreader[no head,column count=6,tabular=rrrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{corpusabg.csv}{}{%
  \csviffirstrow{\myhead{\csvcoli} & \myhead{\csvcolii} & \myhead{\csvcoliii}
    & \myhead{\csvcoliv} & \myhead{\csvcolv} & \myhead{\csvcolvi}
    }{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\end{document}
```